# Options for Query execution in Power BI M Query

Tags: performance, powerbi

Has anyone else had issues (and solved them!) with very slow queries in Power BI when using the "Edit Query" (or Power M Query) side of PowerBI?

I am using multiple nested (using the Reference option - not Duplicate) queries (to get different aggregation levels). All based on a single table read from a large csv file.

I expected the data to be read once to the base table and then each derived table would extract data from the locally stored base table. But it seems to go back to the source data multiple times. This takes the run time to over 15 minutes.

Are there options to stop Power BI from going back to the source for each of these?

Comment: Maybe try [Table.Buffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/table-buffer)?

Comment: Thank you. I tried that. The problem is that Power BI still treats each query as a totally separate sequence of steps rather than a single step (reading the source) with a number of dependent steps. That is true even if I disable parallel queries in options. And no evidence that once the base query has been executed (including the buffered table) that it is speeding up the others. I might try rolling intermediate steps into the queries I am presenting to the reporting side of Power BI. & I will look at File -> Import -> Excel Workbook Contents. As long as I can re-import in order to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: it turned out that the folder where the input csv was being held was extraordinarily slow. When we moved it to test alternatives, the speed problem went away.

I am not sure that you can avoid multiple rereads of an input Excel file in Power BI